# Can set PipeTransform multiple filter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Can set PipeTransform multiple filter ?

I try

```
 posts;
  postss;
    transform(items: any[]): any[] {
             if (items && items.length)
             this.posts = items.filter(it => it.library = it.library.replace("WH","Warehouse"));
             this.postss = items.filter(it => it.collection = it.collection.replace("CL","Central Library"));                                                        

             return this.posts,this.postss;
         }
```

This does not work

but

```
posts; 
transform(items: any[]): any[] {
                 if (items && items.length)
                 this.posts = items.filter(it => it.library = it.library.replace("WH","Warehouse"));
return this.posts;
             }
```

this works.

Comment: return this.posts,this.postss;   what is mean????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you need to change each item in `items` array you don't need to use `filter`, use `forEach` instead and apply your changes:

```
         transform(items: any[]): any[] {
             if (items && items.length){
                 items.forEach((it,index,array) => {
                   array[index].library = it.library.replace("WH","Warehouse"); 
                   array[index].collection = it.collection.replace("CL","Central Library");
                 });                                                        
             }
             return items ;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.posts.concat(this.postss);
```

From the docs for [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> The `concat()` method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.